# Link_to and ajax request in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to

I have the following:

```
<%= link_to "Some_link", some_path, class: "btn btn-success btn-xs", id: "contact", "data-sid" => item.id %>
```

In my application.js I have:

```
$('#contact').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var item_id = $(this).data('sid');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/somepath'+ item_id,
      success: function(data) {
       $("#edit-project-modal").find("input[name='id']").val(data.id);
       $("#edit-project-modal").find("input[name='name']").val(data.name);

     },

      error: function() {
       window.alert('Error Loading Item!!');
      }
   });
});
```

The path "some_path" will have a form for the user to complete. Saying that, what I really want to achieve is when user click the link "Some_link", the link can redirect the user to "some_path" but before that I want to perform the ajax request to load data into the form. I do not know if I can use :remote=>"true" in this case. What is happening now is that when I click the link the ajax works but it is not sending me to the page.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can I just ask, what is the driving force for wanting to populate the form but also redirect? I'm struggling to understand the need for AJAX here at all.

Comment: @henners66 I use ajax to request API data. I will use this data to fill out part of the form. When I click the link I see that the ajax request works but is not taking me anywhere.

Comment: @henners66 The path on the link is not the same as the path to call the API data.

Comment: ok i understand that but, I still don't understand why you are attempting to do this. a) are you expecting to be able to click on the link and for it to do the AJAX request AND the standard HTTP GET ? b) if you are - why are you going to the trouble of populating data on the form and then immediately navigate away from the page? This is what I'm struggling to understand :)

Comment: The link is not in the form page. This link is located in another part of my app. I am trying to use link_to helper to take the user to the form page and make the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now I understand your requirement a lot better, I feel I am more able to help you. You have very much overcomplicated things and the way you are trying to solve this just will not work.

The way it stands at the moment `$('#contact').click(function (e)` is capturing the click event and then attempting to do the AJAX query - I assume your are sending back the data from your controller and not doing any rendering from that. You receive the data and then attempt to populate the form fields, but of course those form fields don't exist ... you haven't navigated to that page - quite likely your jquery at this point is failing silently.

Now because you have swallowed the event and prevented the default behaviour the original path of your link is not followed. Even if you allowed the event to propagate it would not work as highlighted in the previous paragraph.

Ok, without knowing what your further requirements are, to me it seems all you need to do is

1. remove all that jquery.
2. Allow the link_to to just hit your action as a normal HTTP GET.

   `<%= link_to edit_item_path(item), class: "btn btn-success btn-xs", id: "contact" %>`

   ** assumes you have an ItemController with an edit action and that the routing is setup as

   `edit_item GET    /items/:id/edit(.:format)       items#edit`
3. Set your data as an instance variable in your controller

   `@item = Item.find(params[:id])`
4. Render the form as html.erb using the instance variable -

For example,

```
<%= form_for @item, url: item_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <input type='submit'/>
<% end %>
```

Just a straightforward navigation to a form.

Comment: I can do that but my question now is how can I have the id att of this specific item who has the link linked to it. I have a list of items and all of them individually have this link attach. If you notice on my link_to I am recording the item id. Thanks for your help.

Comment: just simply `<%= link_to "Some_link", some_path(item), class: "btn btn-success btn-xs", id: "contact" %>` assuming you have something like that in your routing - normally you would have an edit action in your controller and the route would look like : `edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)       users#edit` which would be invoked as `<%= link_to edit_user_path(user) %>` which would hit the `edit` action on the `UserController` - i assume this is what you are trying to do ... edit an existing model entity.

Comment: updated the solution to make it a lot more clearer i hope

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your example really help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to:

1. Click "Some Link" (through AJAX)
2. Then, Contact form appears just below "Some Link"

You may use the following:

```
<%= link_to "Some_link", some_path, class: "btn btn-success btn-xs", id: "contact", "data-sid" => item.id %>
<section id='contact-form'></section>

$('#contact').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var item_id = $(this).data('sid');

  $('#contact-form').load('/somepath'+ item_id, function(response, status, xhr){
    if (status === "error") {
      window.alert('Error Loading Form!!');
    }
    else {
      window.alert('Success Loading Form!!');
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: The some_path will take me to the form and the ajax URL path is the API path to request json data. They are different. Sorry.